# No tests found matching Method - Unit Test PowerMockito

Tags: unit-testing, spring-mvc, powermockito

I used @Preparefortest inner class

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
 public class TestClass{

 @PrepareForTest({myclass.class})
 @Test()
 public void testCase1() throws Exception {
    mycode here
 }

 @Test()
 public void testCase2() throws Exception{
    mycode here
 }
}
```

When i run coverage test for class TestClass it's success! However when i run only testCase1() it's error initializationError "java.lang.Exception: No tests found matching Method testCase1".

Comment: Please, provide more information how you run only one TC? Which tool do you use?

Comment: I run UT in intelliJ IDE 14.1.4 and i click right mouse for testCase1() -> choice Run 'authenticateNomal...()' to test only this case.